# How do you detect touch slide (touch enter) across elements in JavaScript (or Vue)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, vuejs3, touch

I'm trying to detect a touch event in Vue (particularly) when you slide across components like this in touch/mobile:

[image: Touch and slide]

At present, I can trigger the touch event for 1, but 2 and 3 aren't triggered when sliding over. This would be analogous to hover or enter in non-mobile devices.

The simple Vue would be as follows.

```
<template v-for="(word, id) in sentence">
   <someComponent @touchmove="doSomething(id)"></someComponent>
</template>
```

However this doesn't work. The touchmove is only detected for the element which first received the touch (1 in the image), but not the subsequent elements. Moving the `@touchmove` to `<someComponent>` doesn't work either.

In short, I'm trying to make a slide be like a hover and the touching finger trigger a tooltip without the need to raise the finger.

(Is the only way to put the touch event on the whole screen and attempt to detect which element is 'under' the finger?)

Comment: You can make them have a common parent that handles the whole slide

Comment: @EstusFlask How would you then detect which component the 'touch' is over?

Comment: @Gazzer, did you find a solution for this? I'm trying Vue3TouchEvents https://github.com/robinrodricks/vue3-touch-events#readme but still cannot wotk out how to find the dragged-over or dropped-onto item.

Comment: @quilkin I could only use the parent then use co-ordinates of children, and touch to children that way. I found a janky solution but since it wasn't a major consideration I'll be revisiting later