# How to implement Touch Listener in Vue for items in loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, touch, listener

I have a translation system where a user can click on a word to get more information: translation, frequency, and so forth in a popover (using [Floating UI](https://floating-ui.com/)). A single page can have up to 500 words or so. The very basic Vue code is as follows:

```
    // parent
    <template>
    <div class='parser-wrap' v-touch:drag="onDrag">    
        <template v-for="(word, wid) in sentence">
            <word-component 
               :id="childId(wid)" 
               :isHovering="isHovering(childId(wid))" 
               :word="word"></word-component>
        </template>
    </div>
    </template>

    //word-component (child)
    <template>
        <span v-html="output(word)" 
              @touchstart="doTouchStart"> // move this to parent ? 
        </span>
    </template>
```

Now there are a couple of issues and approaches. For `v-touch:drag` using [vue3-touch-events](https://github.com/robinrodricks/vue3-touch-events) there is no option but to put the drag event in the parent rather than the child `<word-component>` (as there is [no other way to detect touch enter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75350309/224653)).

My question is: what is the best place to put the listener for `@touchstart`? Putting in the child is the easiest approach but it means 500 listeners - does this impact performance?

On the other hand, if I put in the parent how do I detect which child `<word-component>` has been touched? At present, I'm using `document.elementFromPoint` getting the id from the child, then passing whether this matches the childId, and passing the isHovering prop back to the child. This seems janky to say the least :-)

In short, what is the most efficient way to have a **touchevent** on the parent, but communicate to the child 'you have been touched'. Or is it fine to have hundreds of listeners by putting them into the `<word-component>`.

(Note: words are not unique so I cannot use a word id, and going to the next page involves grabbing new sentences. In reality, the childId is a combination of 'pagecount-sentencecount-wordcount' but to simplify the above code I have just used `childId(w)` for illustration purposes).

Comment: What happens if you put the listener in the child? Does your program's responsiveness appear to suffer from this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (as a Python fan thats a great name by the way :-) At present I do put the listener in the child and I can't at present see much responsiveness issues but this is not really my expertise. Since the system will also be used on various mobile phones I'm wondering if such listeners fundamentally affect performance or not. (Since the drag event *must* be in the parent anyway, it would also be more consistent to have all listeners in the parent).

Comment: I imagine that you would still need a listener in the child for each word, and then emit it to the parent

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is possible to put in parent - you detect which child has been clicked, and use a watcher on the child. This is what I must do for the drag event anyway as there is no other way to detect draginto. My real question is: is there an efficient way to detect which child I touched from the parent rather than the janky roundtrip I'm using now?